# Manipulated input fields are not beeing sent to the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, kendo-ui

I am using kendo schedule with a custom template.

```
...
      .Editable(editable => { editable.TemplateName("_CustomTemplate"); }))
...
```

template

```
 ...
        <div class="k-edit-label">
            @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title))
        </div>
        <div data-container-for="title" class="k-edit-field">
            @(Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "k-textbox", data_bind = "value:title" }))
        </div>
    ...
```

Any appoach to manipulate the `model.Title`field fails.
After binding a value per `js` it is not beeing sent to the server anymore. The fields value remains empty or doesn't even show up.
I'd say I tryed almost everything I could find about this topic in order to get this to work but I failed.
Also adding a new `<input>` or even creating an additional field in the model and modify this did not work.

It seems that is not possible to set any input value per *js* that will actually be sent to the server and are not only beeing display in the view.
At least not by doing it like this:

```
 $('#Title').attr('value', data);
 or
 $('#Title').val(data);
```

As I cannot believe that this is a general issue, I suspect kendo schedule / template is involved here.

In case you're wondering why I am trying to manipulate the input fields value in ther first place, here's the thing:

The schedule which I want to create using the custom template corresponds to an event. I want to set the default value title of the schedule to the value of a field that is stored in event. I can only get this value after the schedule model hast been instatiated as there is no connection between this model and the events model.
I though I could simply request the desired value from the event by `ajax` and update the `<input>` but  I was wrong...

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kendo UI edit forms generally rely on the edit textboxes to fire a `change` event in order to update the underlying model (data item).

If you are manipulating values programmatically, then trigger the `change` event manually.

```
$("#Title").val(data).trigger("change");
```

On the other hand, the proper way to change model values programmatically is via the Kendo UI Model's [`set`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#methods-set) method. In open edit form scenarios you can obtain the model ([event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/schedulerevent)) as `e.event` in the Scheduler's [`edit`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#events-edit) event.

```
e.event.set("title", data);
```

Comment: I also tried to get to the underlying model but I searched in the add event

Comment: anyway, I would come up with the set method.